# For those running web apps and websites with transactional emails, how much do they affect your server?

Tags: smtp, email

I'm doing a little research on the matter, because I am genuinely curious how do transactional emails affect server load and resources? I guess to help answer the question, I'm looking for the following:

- How many emails do you send out on a monthly basis from transactions? (Sign-ups, achievements, that kind of stuff)
- How does it affect your server load? Do you find that you have to dedicate a separate SMTP server box?
- How have you optimized for transactional emails?
- Would it have been easier to get a hosted solution?

Appreciate any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send about 2k a month (low) and email sending isn't really resource intensive until you hit silly high numbers.

Even with a volume this low I outsource it. Why? It makes it much easier to get better delivery rates, and makes it easier to track bounces, spam reports, all that other fun stuff. They also handle things like whitelisting and throttling the amount of e-mail sent to a single ISP so it doesn't all get rejected based on volume alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - would you mind me asking whom do you outsource it to and what are their costs?

Comment: For transactional emails I use postmarkapp.com for the project I'm still maintaining, and I've used sendgrid.com for other client projects, which is also excellent. Postmark is $1.50/1000 emails; sendgrid has a higher barrier to entry which is $80/month if you don't want their name on your emails. Sorry about the slow response!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the response. :) How is your experience with PostmarkApp and would you change anything?

Comment: Othen then some of their docs being somewhat unclear, I have no complaints with the service. I think they are fairly new and seem to be changing things like documentation as they go along.

Comment: Ah, do they have deliverability analytics? From my initial impressions of them, they are just a mailing service and don't have much else!

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project (in health care) that sent many thousands of short emails a day, both to computer users and pager users (stuff like "Your patient's lab results are ready.")

The overhead for sending email on your web server and SMTP server is truly tiny.   If you only have one machine you'll be fine.  If you can stand up a separate virtual machine to handle your email, or use the SMTP server furnished by your email service, you'll have greater robustness.

But if you use an email service's SMTP, you'll have to convince them that you're not cranking out spam.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you keep that sort of technology in-house o do you outsource it? One of the things I am definitely exploring.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your q until now.  Outsourcing your SMTP service may work fine, and may not. Public SMTP servers use a variety of security techniques to authenticate their clients (to keep spambots at bay).  If you have to use TLS (f/k/a SSL) to connect, you will have higher overhead.  SMTP is a lightweight service run on free software so it's not hard to run in house.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. I would assume it isn't hard to run, but all of the maintenance and security stuff is quite a turn off.